# Google Ad unit floating on top left of the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, adsense

After placing the Google AdSense ad unit in my site at [ssadic.com](https://ssadic.com) as below, the ad unit is floating and displays on the top left corner of the page instead of within the desired div.

```
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">광고</div>
            <div class="card-body" style="padding:5px !important">
                
                 <!--- Google Ad Unit --->

            </div>
        </div>
```

The issue is only showing on desktop(not mobile) and only on Chrome(not Safari)
Is there a way to force the ad to position within the div area?

Attaching screenshot of the issue : [ad unit floating on top left instead of within](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UQC9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` and `top left`

**Bootstrap**

```html
<div class="position-fixed top-0 start-0">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">광고</div>
            <div class="card-body" style="padding:5px !important">
                
                <!--- Google Ad Unit --->

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Only Css**

```css
.card {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Also you can set `bottom: 0; right: 0`